# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'subsample')

Tags: python, pandas, keras, tensorflow2.0

i am trying to implement the following code but it is throwing an error

TypeError

```
Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-29-6ed67c712ed4> in <module>()
     28     return model    
     29   
---> 30 model = nvidia_model()     
     31 print(model.summary())  
     32 # dead relu problem: when a node in the network essentially dies and only feeds value of 0 to the following nodes.

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs, error_message)
    776   for kwarg in kwargs:
    777     if kwarg not in allowed_kwargs:
--> 778       raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
    779 
    780 

TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'subsample')
```

## Defining Nvidia Model

```
def nvidia_model():    
    model= Sequential()
     
    model.add(Convolution2D(24, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), input_shape=(66, 200, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(36, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(48, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
    model.add(Flatten())
  
    model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
    model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
    model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
    model.add(Dense(1)) # output the predicted steering angle 
  
    optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-4)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

model = nvidia_model()    
print(model.summary())
```

Comment: Add a standalone code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this problem? I have the same :/

Answer (score 1):

```py
def nvidia_model():    
    model= Sequential()
     
    model.add(Convolution2D(24, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), input_shape=(66, 200, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(36, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(48, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
    model.add(Flatten())
  
    model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
    model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
    model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
    model.add(Dense(1)) # output the predicted steering angle 
  
    optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-4)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

model = nvidia_model()    
print(model.summary())
```

Instead of this, replace the code with the following:

```py
def nvidia_model():    
    model= Sequential()
     
    model.add(Convolution2D(24, (5, 5), subsample=(2, 2), input_shape=(66, 200, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(36, (5, 5), subsample=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(48, (5, 5), subsample=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
    model.add(Flatten())
  
    model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
    model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
    model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  
    model.add(Dense(1)) # output the predicted steering angle 
  
    optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-4)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

model = nvidia_model()    
print(model.summary())
```

(Notice I added parentheses.) If still the code doesn't work then replace `subsample` with `strides` everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on the same error. Here's what I found:

`Convolution2D` is a Keras v1 API (docs: https://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.2/layers/convolutional/)

`Conv2D` is the newer v2 API (docs: https://faroit.com/keras-docs/2.0.5/layers/convolutional/).

I got it working with the following changes:

1. Changed `import Convolution2D` to `import Conv2D`
2. Changed

```
model.add(Convolution2D(24, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), input_shape=(66, 200, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(36, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(48, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
```

to

```
  model.add(Conv2D(24, 5, 2, input_shape = (66, 200, 3), activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(36, 5, 2, activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(48, 5, 2, activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu'))
```

Comment: Where is your subsample?

Answer (score -1):

Try using pooling instead of subsample. Usually that will work.

Comment: tried but its throwing an error of pool_size not defined

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution!!

It is because use the argument for Kernel as a tuple. So yah doing (5,5) for it worked for me.

p.s. this marks the first answer I ever gave, yay